# Media запросы не срабатывает?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Media запросы не срабатывает этом  [сайте](https://gaztranskomplekt.ru)  не знаю почему ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

записан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в самом CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px;) { /* ";" тут лишняя */
  #logo {
    background-color: red;  
  } 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]